# unable to connect to node rabbit@localhost: nodedown , despite I copied the cookie all over

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to follow this guide https://www.rabbitmq.com/pacemaker.html to install RabbitMQ on top of pacemaker.
(I know there is already a newer system but I'm trying this one).

I have two ubuntu 16.04 machine called rabbitmq1 & rabbitmq2 which able to ping each other by name (rabbitmq version 3.6.15 Erlang 20.2) with working pacemaker, DRDB and Corosync.

After all was set I added a this resource to pacemaker:
configure primitive bunny ocf:rabbitmq:rabbitmq-server params mnesia_base="/media/drbd1"

This is the error I got:

> Hostname mismatch: node "rabbit@rabbitmq1" believes its host is
>   different. Please ensure that hostnames resolve the same way locally
>   and on "rabbit@rabbitmq1"

current node details:

> - node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-65@rabbitmq1'
> - home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq -
> - cookie hash: O9bMZ3LMnkSPaakjdRYHuw==

I  tried copying this erlang cookie file to all usere home folder from this location /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie (both to the home folder of root user and to the home folder or rabbitmq user) but it's not helping.
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Hostname mismatch: node "rabbit@rabbitmq1" believes its host is different` is a very clear error. DNS is not configured correctly. What is the output of `nslookup rabbitmq1`?

Comment: Hi @LukeBakken,
Thank you for your reply, I dont use DNS as I use Hosts file instead.

Comment: Here is the output of my /etc/hosts file:

127.0.0.1       rabbitmq1
172.29.87.115   rabbitmq1
172.29.87.116   rabbitmq2

Here is the output of my hostname file /etc/hostname:
rabbitmq1

This is the output of the command "hostname":
rabbitmq1

both machines able to ping each other by name, "rabbitmqctl -n rabbit@rabbitmq1 status" works well while "rabbitmqctl -n rabbit@localhost status" gives error 
What could be the issue

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

One scenario is not to have the ***exact*** domain name when trying to connect. The domain name suffixing node name is *case sensitive*.

Use `rabbit@rabbitmq1` won't reach the node hosted on `RabbitMQ1`, despite the fact that hosts file has been correctly configured.